# Is there a bug in controlled rounding using `exp`?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, ieee-754

I'm observing incorrect (IMO) rounding behaviour on some platforms as follows:

Calculate the value of `log(2)` under rounding modes to `FE_DOWNWARD` and `FE_UPWARD` (see `<fenv.h>`). In all cases I've seen, the rounded downward result is less than the rounded upward result, which is what I would expect (result is inexact).

Now using the same rounding modes, call `exp` with each result. Since `exp` is monotonically increasing (slope is ~2 in the area of interest), I would expect the these results to be even further apart. But on some platforms tested, the two results from `exp` are equivalent.

Here's a simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

int main(void) {
  fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
  double xlo = log(2);
  double xxlo = exp(xlo);
  printf("xlo=%.16e xxlo=%.16e\n",xlo,xxlo);

  fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
  double xhi = log(2);
  double xxhi = exp(xhi);
  printf("xhi=%.16e xxhi=%.16e\n",xhi,xxhi); 

  printf("Delta x=%.16e\n",xhi-xlo);
  if (xxlo == xxhi) 
    printf("FAIL\n");
  else 
    printf("Delta xx=%.16e\n",xxhi-xxlo);

  return 0;
}
```

One (good) result on Xeon E5520  @ 2.27GHz:

```
xlo=6.9314718055994528e-01 xxlo=1.9999999999999997e+00
xhi=6.9314718055994540e-01 xxhi=2.0000000000000005e+00
Delta x=1.1102230246251566e-16
Delta xx=6.6613381477509393e-16
```

Other processors that have passed the test: AMD Ryzen 9 3950X, Intel i7-5557U, Intel i7-3770, Intel m7-6Y75.

But a couple have reportedly failed (xxlo==xxhi): Intel E5-2650 and AMD EPYC 7401, coincidentally both server class machines. I don't have direct access to those but running the test at https://repl.it/languages/c also fails:

```
clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
 clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
 ./main
xlo=6.93147180559945286e-01 xxlo=2.00000000000000000e+00
xhi=6.93147180559945398e-01 xxhi=2.00000000000000000e+00
Delta x=1.11022302462515655e-16
FAIL
```

I'm not so much interested in the actual precision of the results, but more in the relative values. So am I missing something, or is this just wrong? And if it's wrong, is it hardware rounding error or issues with the software math libraries, or even the compiler/settings? I'm also interested in collecting any results from running the simple test to see if any additional conclusions can be drawn from that data.

Comment: There is actually no guarantee that `exp` respects the rounding mode. See Appendix F.10 paragraph 10 of the C standard: "Whether the functions honor the rounding direction mode is implementation-defined, unless explicitly specified otherwise." `exp()` is not one of the (very few) functions explicitly specified to obey the rounding direction.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.6 Floating-point environment <fenv.h> 3 Certain programming conventions support the intended model of use for the floating-
point environment: 206)
[...]
— a function call is assumed to require default floating-point control modes, unless its
documentation promises otherwise;*. I'm not seeing anything that suggests that `exp()` or `log()` are prepared to handle non-default rounding settings.

Comment: So it would appear that the C function libraries not only do not guarantee any level of precision, but the result can't even be bounded using rounding modes.

Are there any arithmetic functions (e.g., +,*, ..) that can be bounded in this fashion? Or is this implied by the floating point standards and hardware instruction sets? The only thing I could find in C11 was binary-decimal conversions were correctly rounded according to current rounding mode. 

Is anybody aware of a list of C arithmetic operations/functions with known behaviour in this context?

Comment: It's C. Why were you expecting sophistication and an elegant design that supports sane programming? (To be fair, many languages will inherit this behavior because they won't bother with the considerable effort to implement better floating-point handling, and will instead use what C offers.)

Comment: Sigh. Not really a C programmer, but hoped after 30 years of floating point standardization, some of the bugs would be worked out. And you're probably right, most other (general purpose) languages will just follow behind.

Comment: A glimmer of hope: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html#Errors-in-Math-Functions

If the error values are to be believed, `nexttoward` (called a suitable number of times) can be used to bound the function results. Any problems with that?

Comment: `+,-,*,/` can be expected to be within 0.5 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of the correct answer for round to nearest and 0.999.. ULP for others.  For math functions like `exp, sin`, _better_ libraries will be only within 1.1 ULP, regardless of round mode..  Weak libraries, simply get worse.  All part of the [table maker's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Table-maker's_dilemma)

Comment: "not so much interested in the actual precision of the results, but more in the relative values. " --> Curious, ridgeworks, would you like a `exp()` that was nicely monotonic but off many ULPs or a very precise one that wobbled?  How much precision would you sacrifice for monotonicity?

Comment: After 30 years of floating point standardization, many of the bugs have been worked out.  The non-monotonicity OP seeks is not as high a goal as low ULP error.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "would you like a exp() that was nicely monotonic but off many ULPs or a very precise one that wobbled? How much precision would you sacrifice for monotonicity?"  My objective is to produce a pair of floating point values guaranteed to contain the answer. How much precision would I have to sacrifice?

Comment: @ridgeworks Now that [contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641716/is-there-a-bug-in-controlled-rounding-using-exp?noredirect=1#comment107295848_60641716) is interesting! - as that is the true goal.  I suspect with a modestly good `exp()`, the function result will _always_ be within 2 ( or maybe 1.49999...) ULP of the math result.  Will need to ponder.  Fun thought: only `exp(0)` can give an _exactly_ correct answer.  All other `exp(some_double)` are off a wee bit.  (`double` is rational, e^x is irrational)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So I initially (and naively) thought I could use rounding modes so the "container" would be 1 ULP wide. It now appears I'll have to use `nexttoward` twice (1.499999... is the same as 2 for this purpose), so the container is 4ULP wide. BTW are any of these error estimates published for the commonly used libc's? Is ±2 reasonably safe for any function?

Comment: `float` libraries could iterate over all values and find worst case.  `double, long double` could statistically demonstrate and/or have a proof along with its algorithm to show worst case.  I suspect unless you are using a well known/popular source code, these worst case ULP results will not be available - it is "work" to get this. ±2 is reasonably safe with a good library - Now how to we know it the library is good?  Code could be written to give a _guaranteed_ `exp_lo()` and `exp_hi()`, but such functions, again are "work" to not be overly cautions.

Comment: Can you show us the values in HEX?

Comment: IIRC, the IEEE-754 initially specified "correctly rounded" for +-*/ and sqrt.  But nothing else, because it was deemed too difficult.  (Perhaps bin <->decimal was also required to be correctly rounded.)

Answer (score 0):

The spread (round-down to round-up) gets magnified by the derivative of the function.  So, if your original bound is 1ULP, I would expect exp(x) at 2.0 to have a spread of 3.  That's (original spread) * (derivative) + 1.  The +1 is because you are doing another round-down and round-up.

If the derivative is 2.5, I would expect the output spread to be between 3 and 4.

Please provide the hex for the numbers; this should be definitive by avoiding the bin<->dec conversions (which seem to be flawed on some of the machines, too).

None of what I have said invalidates your conclusion that the servers have inconsistent hardware, hence flawed IEEE implementation.

Oh, one more thing; check to see if the optimizer worked too hard -- by eliminating the exp after seeing the log.  Or maybe using an FMA, which sometimes gives you *better* rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

@Rick James

I agree with your diagnosis. Here's the output from my original program with additional print statements providing the hex data. I'm not much of a C programmer, so if this isn't what you requested, be more explicit.

```
xlo=6.9314718055994528e-01 xxlo=2.0000000000000000e+00
xlo=0x1.62e42fefa39efp-1 xxlo=0x1p+1
xhi=6.9314718055994540e-01 xxhi=2.0000000000000000e+00
xhi=0x1.62e42fefa39fp-1 xxhi=0x1p+1
Delta x=1.1102230246251566e-16
Delta x=0x1p-53
FAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks for

> My objective is to produce a pair of floating point values guaranteed to contain the answer.

All C implementations are lazy enough to just (barely) satisfy the C standard, as mentioned in the comments, and this is enough to satisfy the vast majority of users, and with a very good performance given the difficulties to comply to all platforms, toolchains, etc.

If you require upper and lower bounds to some mathematical univariate function, then there are very good interval arithmetic libraries such as [GNU MPRIA](https://www.gnu.org/software/mpria/), and most recently the [Arb Library](https://arblib.org/), which provide rigourous enclosing bounds for the evaluation of many mathematical functions with very good independency of platform (mainly because they rely on the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)).